# how to reverse a stack using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to reverse stack without using extra space through recursion. But unable to find my error.

Here is my code. It is printing the same stack again.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
void insert( stack<int>& k , int j){
    k.push(j);
}
void reverse(stack<int> &s){
    if(s.empty()){
        return;
    }
    int temp = s.top();
    s.pop();
    reverse(s);
    insert(s,temp);
}
int main()
{   
    stack<int>s;
    for( int i = 5;i>0;i--){
        s.push(i);
    }
    reverse(s);
    while(!s.empty()){
       cout << s.top() << " ";
       s.pop();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you need to do inplace? It seems very hard with a stack structure

Comment: you cannot do it without additional memory. When you remove top element you can only put it back on top (what your code does) or place it at the bottom of a different stack

Comment: zen exercise: try to reverse a stack of papers on your desk. You are only allowed to remove the top sheet and only allowed to put a sheet on top. You are not allowed to use a second stack of paper, at any time all sheets are either on the stack or one paper is in your hand

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number he needs an additional stack for sure, but the sum of the memory of the two stacks could be equal to the original one at every point.

Comment: `I am trying to reverse stack without using extra space through recursion.` Because you use recursion your `int temp` will eat up extra space, so you won't have any benefit regarding space compared to just creating a second `std::stack`.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi ok, but strictly speaking, even an empty `std::stack` occupies memory. And a `std::deque` (default container for `std::stack`) does not give you fine grained control over allocated memory

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sure, if it is a purely academic question the answer is no, if it has a real life application, this can be done with a "constant" increase of memory instead of linear.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi if it is "real life" one should use a simple loop, no?

Comment: Recursion uses space, so the whole endeavour is based on a false premise. You will use extra space one way or another. You can say "I want all extra space to be allocated in recursion and not by other means", but it doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number indeed, I probably would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert()` function is incorrect since you only push temp into the stack and once the stack is empty the value of temp will be 5 so 5 is pushed then 4 and so on. Hence the stack is filled in the same order. This `insert()` should work.

```
void insert( stack<int>& k , int j){
    if(k.empty()){
        k.push(j);
        return;
    }
    int temp = k.top();
    k.pop();
    insert(k, j);
    k.push(temp);
}
```

`insert()` just inserts `j` to the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursivity is not correct. You remove the top, call the same function (reverse) recursively and then push it back on top. This does not change its position! The same applies to all elements recursively: they do not change their position. A pure recursive solution (without using another stack or any data structure like an array or a list) to your problem is impossible.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Quimby I quote from the question: "But unable to find my error". The asker wants to know his error. I show him where is the error!